# Run software from USB device

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, installation, windows-installer

I am developing a desktop based application using VC++.
I have stuck on one problem that the application should run through USB too.

I have searched for the answer I get to know that I can do it by changing installation path to `USB` device from this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3473672/3110262).

But my application needs some supporting platform like `.Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile`, and some `redistributables` for running application.

So, Can anyone tell me how can I make my application running through USB?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

regarding `.Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile`

As far as i know the .Net runtime can not be included in an Application.
The PC you want to execute your Application on needs to have the proper Runtime Version installed, it doesn't matter if its running from USB or not.

Here is a good article about the topic:
http://johnhaller.com/useful-stuff/dot-net-portable-apps
it basically concludes that you have to chose the .Net version depending on your target OS.
for Windows Vista and Windows 7 it would be .Net 2.0,
for Windows 8 it would be .Net 4.0

There might be a solution using [Portable.Net](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable.NET) or [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono) but thats a bit above my developer skills :)

regarding `redistributables`

it really depends on what kind of redists you mean, if its the visual c++ redist you only need to include the right DLL, for other redists im not sure.

Btw Apps running from USB Sticks are usually called 'portable app', if you search for dotnet portable apps you can find quite some information.